# Unable to boot with nvidia gpu and blacklisted nouveau

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I have some problem with running Ubuntu on a custom laptop.
I have build a motherboard, it has gtx1050ti with custom memory config, different gpio setting and enabled gc6. I can boot windows, I can install the default NVIDIA driver and run furmark, but Ubuntu doesn't work.
If I try to boot Ubuntu even with blacklisted nouveau, it hangs completely, the computer becomes a brick. It doesn't even save logs. With disabled pci-e it boots normal.
Tiny Linux boots normally. How can I tell Ubuntu to not even touch my gpu?
I just want to edit some registers and then insert nouveau module.

Comment: try "safe graphics"?

Comment: no, tried already

Comment: We're limited with what we can provide, you've not told us what Ubuntu product you're asking about, not what release of that product.  If it's a LTS release for example you have kernel stack choices but we don't know if those options exist for you as you've not told us what product (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Core..) & what release  (*for most products the ISO used to install sets the kernel default*)

Comment: It is Ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS with 5.19 kernel